# Android Studio unable to launch - Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I download Android studio for Mac. When i am trying to launch application it is throwing exception below.
My current Java version is 1.8.0_25.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyGenerator(JsseJce.java:223)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:91)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.checkInternetConnection(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.fetchPackages(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.access$100(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider$2.compute(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider$2.compute(AndroidStudioWelcomeScreenProvider.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$4.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:240)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with different versions of the local_policy and US_export_policy jars. [Java Bugdatabase](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6647104) also refers to corrupted jars causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and Re-install your Java Development Kits (This worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio needs JRE 6 to launch, though you can use JDK 1.6 or JDK1.7 later with the project.
Download Java 6 for Mac from here and install and then launch Android Studio.
It works!!